# A word to refer to the sound that an elevator makes when its cables are having problems?

Tags: single-word-requests

Sometimes when you are going up an elevator, you kind of hear this sound as if the cables that are lifting the elevator are having some difficulties. Like the sound that a car makes when it abruptly stops.

What's a word to refer to that sound?

All I could think of was something like "a **grinding** sound came from above."

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Grind is good. _A twanging sound_ comes to mind

Comment: I think this is POB, since it all depends on exactly what *kind* of "difficulties" the elevator is having.

Comment: I think a good-word does not exist here because the auctual phenomenon is too wrapped-up in technical explanation of how that noise is produced.  What everyone knows is that a noisy elevator is a dangerous elevator.

Comment: And once again, an upvote, a star, and a close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest *[screeching](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/screech)*:

> : a high shrill piercing cry usually expressing pain or terror

Comment: beat me to the punch :)

Comment: @cornbread ninja 麵包忍者 I think that's the word I was looking for. Thanks! By the way (麵包 = bread 忍者 = ninja. Where is the corn :D)?

Comment: @janoChen I couldn't find the character for corn! :D  How about 玉米麵包忍者?

Comment: @cornbreadninja麵包忍者 It's 玉米麵包. I happen to speak Chinese. I've never seen that kind of bread though, ha.

Comment: "Squeal" could be similarly used.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use ***graunch***, which is rather onomatopoeic. And would you believe it, it's in the dictionary, even though my spell-checker doesn't like it.

> **graunch** *verb*
>   [no object]
>   make a crunching or grinding noise:
>   *the wheels graunched against a stone wall*

Answer (score 2):

[Onomatopoeias](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/onomatopoeia) are very subjective, and depend entirely on the sound, to say nothing of the different interpretations in different languages for the same sound.  So bear in mind that any answer given is going to be subjective to one's own experience.

You might get a "[creaking](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Creaking)" noise, if the elevator is sticking and the metal parts are trying, but failing, to move against one another. Or if the metal elevator is straining against the cables, or if the wire is being stretched.

"Creaking" works especially well, since it includes both the squeaking sound one might hear from old, rusty, unoiled cables, as well as the grating noise one would hear from the metal parts pushing and grinding against one another.  Even moreso, since it also describes an object that is moving whilst making this sound (A creaking elevator could mean that it is making this sound while moving, both implying the sound and the difficulty with which it moves).

Answer (score 1):

Screech is the word you seem to be referring to when a car stops abruptly ( screech to a halt) which could also apply to the elevator cables under some circumstances I suppose.