# What is the sound made by a handbrake being pulled?

Tags: word-choice

I was considering using "creaking" or "rattling". After some googling, I saw they're both associated with a faulty handbrake. Any other suggestion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A word to refer to the sound that an elevator makes when its cables are having problems?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126433/a-word-to-refer-to-the-sound-that-an-elevator-makes-when-its-cables-are-having-p)

Comment: What type of handbreak?  I initially thought you might mean a bicycle handbreak, but cars, trains, and other devices also have handbreaks that could be pulled, with different effecting sounds.

Comment: @Zibbobz And the same handbrake could make different sounds depending on the amount of lube and extent of past use. What do you think :)

Answer (score 2):

A 'ratcheting sound' is how I would describe it when you pull a handbrake in a car.

Comment: Are you turning this question into an opinion-seeking one by chance? That can make it off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

**Screech**.

Usage:  "When I pulled the handbrake it made a screeching sound and the train finally stopped."

Comment: More likely that it's the train that *screeched* to a stop.